# get ouput from shell script back into a makefile

Tags: bash, scripting, makefile

I've tried something like this:

```
VAR := $(echo \`find . -name ".txt"`)
```

but when I echo $VAR from inside a target, I get nothing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
VAR := $(shell find . -name "*.txt")
```

Comment: thanks, $(shell cmd) works better but I get weird results with: SO_PATH_LIBPREFIX := $(shell for f in find . -name "*"; do dn=$(dirname $f) && fn=$(basename $f) && echo $dn/lib$fn; done) as if $d and $f were not recognised

Comment: make expands the $f etc before passing the string to the shell, so you need to double-up your $ signs...`do dn=$(dirname $$f) && ...`.  There is an explanation why you don't need to double up the $ in '$(dirname ...)`, namely that '$(' is not a variable name to make.